# Overlapping structure when beveling (SVG) curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, path, svg

I hope somebody can give me some tipps although I don't really know how to phrase my problem for a suitable title.

I want to create a path in Inkscape and import it as an SVG to blender. When I create the path only two nodes can be joined, not 3 or more, so I get an overlapping path. [image: overlapping path]

When I import the path to blender, bevel it and create a mesh with it, the structure is still overlapping which causes problems when slicing the object for the 3D printer. [image: overlapping mesh structure]

Is there a way to avoid overlapping or get rid of it? I hope you know what I mean.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Not with curves. A curve cannot be forked, any given point cannot be connected to more than two points. You would need to convert to a mesh and manually create the intersection.

Comment: Try splitting that profile into 2 curves in Illustrator, so they are as different objects before importing into Blender. Also if dealing with intersecting tube like shown on screenshot select all and run Ctrl+F > Intersect (Knife), or (Boolean), depending on situation. In some cases it will cut out inner geometry and give a decent non-manifold mesh. At least it would lessen amount of manual work you do while fixing that in Edit mode

Answer (score 3):

[image: final]

You can do this quite easy with help from TinyCAD add-on and some modifiers.

### Steps:

1. After importing SVG convert it to a mesh - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > ***Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text***.
2. [Enable TinyCAD add-on.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html)
3. In **Edit Mode** select two crossing edges and <kbd>W</kbd> > ***TinyCAD*** > ***VTX Auto***.

   > **Important!** You should have only two edges. Sometimes a little clean up
   >   could be needed as in example below. Use <kbd>X</kbd> > ***Dissolve Vertices*** to do this.

   [image: example]
4. Add **Skin** and **Subdivision** (use level as needed) modifiers.
5. In **Edit Mode** after selecting all vertices scale them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and tweak **Branch Smoothing** in **Skin** modifier as needed.

   [image: 56]